# golang does not update array in a map

Tags: arrays, dictionary, go

```
m := map[int][2]int{1:{0,10}}
m[1][0] = 1
```

I expect the above to work like this

```
a := [2]int{0,10}
a[0] = 1
```

but instead it gives the following error `cannot assign to m[1][0]`

What could be a possible explanation for this?

P.S. I know I can get around the problem by declaring a map of int to slice instead of int to array.

Comment: Curious. It works if you decompose the assignment: https://play.golang.org/p/z87rFaBdq73

Answer (score 4):

The left-hand operand of an [assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) must be [addressable](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators), a map index expression or the blank identifier.

The value `m[1][0]` is not not addressable.   See the [specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators) for a list of what is addressable. A map value is not in that list.

The expression `m[1][0]` is an array index expression, not a map index expression.

To update the value in the map, assign the map value to a variable (which is addressable), update the variable and assign back to the map:

```
t := m[1]
t[0] = 1
m[1] = t
```

Another approach is to use a map of pointers to [2]int:

```
m := map[int]*[2]int{1: {0, 10}}
m[1][0] = 1
```

The array elements are addressable because of the implicit pointer indirection.